# Is CNI still needed when service mesh is used in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, cni, servicemesh

Is CNI ( e.g. Flannel, Calico) is still needed once I start using a service mesh ( e.g. Istio) at Kubernetes clusters?

Answer (score 5):

CNI is a mandatory requirement for having a working Kubernetes cluster but service mesh is not. CNI primarily works at L4 layer whereas service mesh works at L7 layer. Although there might be some bits of overlapping in functionality between a CNI plugin and service mesh they don't completely replace each other.

Comment: and what is the default CNI plugin for kubernetes? I've seen many video tutorials but never seen they care about CNI at all. Or is it some native CNI inside kubernetes?

Comment: There is not a default plugin. Calico is the most popular.